# I was trying to connect mongodb to my server but got this error

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

trying to connect mongodb atlas to my express server it is giving this error

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
          ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at _createMongoClient (F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:805:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:742:29)
    at Mongoose.connect (F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:406:15)
    at F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\db.js:8:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at connectToMongo (F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\db.js:6:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\course\code_with_harry\iNoteBook\backenend\db.js:19:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
```

Try to connect mongo dB atlas to my server but every time I try to run the server it gives me this error

Comment: The error message is clear. The URI string you passed in to `openUri()` is `undefined`. Check it.